# jira4r - how to get a list of my custom fields and any attributes they may have

Tags: list, jira, custom-fields

I'm using jira4r to create and update jira tickets.  I'm trying to update a custom field a particular custom field but am unable to do so.  I thought I had the ID correct for the field (customfield_10017) but I may be wrong.  Is there a way to get a list of custom field names with their IDs using jira4r?  I do not have access to any of the administrative tools.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through a list of them manually and maybe that will help you out..

```
issues = api.getIssuesFromFilter(filter_id).to_a
issues.each do |i|
customFieldValues = i.customFieldValues.to_a
  customFieldValues.each do |custom|
    if custom.customfieldId == "customfield_10319"
      value = custom.values.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

and if you can at least view the source of a Jira ticket, you can see the custom field and it's ID.  Search the source for: **customfield_**